# Is there a more performant alternative to ImageList.Images.Add?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, performance

I have a winforms `ImageList` which contains 200 256x256 images.

When I add the images, 1 by one, half of the programs time spent on the `Add` method according to ANTS .NET profiler.

So the program takes 10 secs to launch and 5 is spent there. That is very slow in my opinion.

I implemented the same thing using `ImageList.Images.AddRange`. The result did not change.

Does anyone know any alternatives or optimizations to solve this? Is the WPF `ImageList` any faster? Is there a faster winforms `ImageList`?

---

#### EDIT:

```
foreach (string imageFile in images)
{
    imageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(imageFile)); // takes pretty much all of program's execution time.
}
```

Comment: Should this question be closed, based on your newer one?

Comment: Hi Jon, I don't think so. This one is for ImadeList.Images.Add, the other one is Images.FromFile. They are similar and I used them in the same app, but both are slowing down the app. But if you think they are the same, feel free :)

Comment: Btw I used the same first sentence in both if that's what concerned you?

Comment: WPF doesn't have an ImageList: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559.aspx Deciding what to use instead would depend on what you're using ImageLists for.

Comment: I am using ImageLists to implement a win7 explorer style view in my app with very large icons.

Comment: Well, if half the time in your app is spent in ImageList.Images.Add and half is spent in Images.FromFile, that sounds like it's doing nothing but adding images... It would be good to see some sample code.

Comment: Jon, you are right. That might just be Image.FromFile. I was doing this late at night, so might be me. Will check and see if this method is slow indeed.

Comment: Just checked the code, and yeah it's like the line where it contains both methods takes 100% and half is method #1, the other is method #2. Not really 50% each, but more like 40-60. Posted code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the album and list views in [PhotoSuru](http://www.photosuru.com/), one of Microsoft's WPF sample applications.  They have a couple different thumbnail view screens that load pretty quickly (all the images are loaded asynchronously, and only the images necessary are loaded).  And there's full source code to get you started if it's what you are looking for.

It not precisely like Picasa (they decided only to show full rows of photos instead of a partially covered row like Picasa), but by implementing your own virtualizing IScrollInfo panel (reasonably straightforward, and Ben Constable has a great [series of posts on it](http://blogs.msdn.com/bencon/archive/2006/01/05/509991.aspx)), you should be able to get the performance you're looking for and the behaviour you want.

A final note: You might be doing this already (are your images stored as 256x256 pixel images?), but whenever you're trying to display image thumbnails, you'll want to avoid loading the full image. Reading 2 MB+ image files off of the disk just to render an entire screenful of 256x256 pixel thumbnails always has a bigger performance hit than reading an appropriately sized small thumbnail image instead.  If you can, cache the thumbnails somewhere (like Windows and Picasa do), or at the very least, try to use the embedded thumbnails in any JPEG files you encounter.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. You mean I prescale images by hand? Is there a way to say "load this 2K image as a 256x256 in .net?

Comment: No, you don't need to do it by hand.  Image.GetThumbnailImage should be able to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a ListView for the UI part using that ImageList?

The general solution to these kind of problems is to only load some of the images, because only some of them are shown at a time, and then load the other as needed. ListView has a [VirtualMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx) property for this kind of scenarios.

Loading and adding 200 images at once may be too much to do, you could load the first shown images and then use a background thread to load the others. Have a look at how Win7 display images, it shows some placeholder when you scroll and then, when the image is loaded it shows the real picture. Be warned that this **is not a simple thing** to do.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing that concerns me is I want a smooth scroll, so no placeholders popping up. I know the count can't be more than 500. So one will be able to quickly browse the images there. But it wuld work if it worked like picasa where you don't see placeholder images but yet it doesn't load all at once, when you scroll.

Comment: Picasa uses prebuilded index with scaled and optimized images, so if you want to achieve similar results, you must use similar methods.

Answer (score 0):

try my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789042/how-to-thumbnail-faster-in-c) to scale-down your image and make a thumbnail out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Load images to `List<Image>`. Then call `ImageList.Images.AddRange(list)`.

```
List<Image> list = new List<Image>();
foreach (string imageFile in images)
{
    list.Add(Image.FromFile(imageFile)); 
}
imageList.Images.AddRange(list.ToArray());
```